# inavlid o_auth signature error while using fatsecret food api

Tags: iphone, oauth, error-handling

I am stuck in invalid oauth signature issue for FatSecret REST api in my iphone app. Below is the response 
`error =     {
        code = 8;
        message = "Invalid signature: oauth_signature 'giWu0JtjgG3OBqD_sBCByz-Q2Gk='";
    };`

I am creating signed request using HMAC_SHA1, for some of the searches its returning the correct signature and in some of the cases its giving above error for food.get and food.search methods

Any help would be useful
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4):

I found getting oauth working with FatSecret rather tedious.  When you email them regarding oauth issues, they direct you to their google group.  Ultimately, I wasn't able to get much help there either but I did post my implementation when I finally figured it out.

It's a complete [node.js foods.search() implementation](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/fatsecret-platform-api/1e4VxsuHTcA/s-WwHJfp1wwJ) -- might be worth a look

Comment: This implementation fails when search expression has a whitespace. FatSecret API returns an invalid oauth signature response. Any ideas oh how to fix that?

Comment: How to pass page_number and max_results in this food_search method ?

Answer (score 1):

It occurred because of the incorrectly encoding the oauth signature. The digest generated should be base64-encoded per the RFC2045 protocol.

Got the solution by replacing occurrence of string "_" with "/" and "-" with "+" while generating o_auth signature.

Hope it will help other users :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that if the base64-encoded oAuth signature had any spaces ("+" after url encoding by RFC3986), I would receive the invalid signature response as well. I performed a check that the oAuth signature string didn't contain the offending character and if it did, I regenerated the oAuth signature. I used a time interval since 1970 as the time stamp (as required by API) and for the nonce, so it was a simple matter of recreating the nonce and time stamp until no spaces were present.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the request method to POST.
2. Enter the URL: https://oauth.fatsecret.com/connect/token.
3. In the Headers section, add the following header:
   Key: Content-Type
   Value: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
4. In the Authorization tab, select "Basic Auth" as the type.
   Username: <YOUR_CLIENT_ID>
   Password: <YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>
5. In the Body tab, select "x-www-form-urlencoded" as the type.
   Add the following key-value pair in the body:
   Key: grant_type
   Value: client_credentials
   Add another key-value pair:
   Key: scope
   Value: basic

Now, you should be able to send the request in Postman. This setup ensures that the client ID and client secret are sent as basic authentication credentials, and the necessary parameters are included in the request body.

Please replace <YOUR_CLIENT_ID> and <YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET> with your actual client ID and client secret provided by FatSecret.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post while receiving the same error.  It turned out that in my case the error was from not noticing in the documentation that you need to add "&" to the end of the API_SECRET before encoding the signature.  To help people in the future, I am posting my solution:

```
import crypto from 'crypto';
import { FS_ID, FS_OA1_API_KEY } from '$env/static/private';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

export default class FatSecretOauth1 {
    constructor(httpMethod, url, inputParameters) {
        this.requestUrl = url;
        this.httpMethod = httpMethod.toUpperCase();
        this.inputParameters = {
            ...inputParameters,
            format: 'json',
            oauth_consumer_key: FS_ID,
            oauth_nonce: uuidv4(),
            oauth_signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
            oauth_timestamp: Math.floor(new Date().getTime()),
            oauth_version: '1.0'
        };
        this.paramString = this.buildRequestParameterString();
        this.signature = this.buildSignature();
        return { paramString: this.paramString, signature: this.signature };
    }

    buildSignature() {
        let method = encodeURIComponent(this.httpMethod);
        let url = encodeURIComponent(this.requestUrl);
        let params = encodeURIComponent(this.paramString);
        let signature = crypto
            .createHmac('sha1', `${FS_OA1_API_KEY}&`) //<-- My error was here with the "&"
            .update(`${method}&${url}&${params}`)
            .digest()
            .toString('base64');
        return encodeURIComponent(signature);
    }

    buildRequestParameterString() {
        let params = '';
        Object.entries(this.inputParameters)
            .sort()
            .forEach((cur) => (params += `&${encodeURI(cur[0])}=${encodeURI(cur[1])}`));
        params = params.substring(1);
        return params;
    }
}
```

Below is the fetch using the parameter string and signature.

```
const searchByID = {
    method: 'food.get.v4',
    food_id: 27443
};

let url = 'https://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api';
let httpMethod = 'POST';

const result = new FatSecretOauth1(httpMethod, url, searchByID);

const response = await fetch(
`${url}?${result.paramString}&oauth_signature=${result.signature}`,
{
    method: httpMethod
});

  const data = await response.json();

  console.log('fetch Data: ', data);

  return { data: data.food };
}
```

I hope this saves someone some time in the future.